# C# SQL Assistance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows

I am currently attempting to write a .net 4.6 console app to work with a database, below is the test database structure and I have tried a number of tutorials in order to set about the best way to insert and update the data and what i seem to come up with seems somewhat cumbersome or not particularly manageable.

```
USE [Test_Table]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Data]
           ([Identifier]
           ,[XDocument]
           ,[XVersion]
           ,[XSubVersion]
           ,[SubmittedBy]
           ,[SubmissionID]
           ,[SubmissionDateTime]
           ,[AssociatedFiles]
           ,[UpdatedXdocument]
           ,[DateTimeUpdated]
           ,[UpdateComments])
     VALUES
           (<Identifier, nvarchar(20),>
           ,<XDocument, xml,>
           ,<XVersion, int,>
           ,<XSubVersion, int,>
           ,<SubmittedBy, nvarchar(20),>
           ,<SubmissionID, nvarchar(20),>
           ,<SubmissionDateTime, datetime,>
           ,<AssociatedFiles, nvarchar(max),>
           ,<UpdatedXdocument, xml,>
           ,<DateTimeUpdated, datetime,>
           ,<UpdateComments, nvarchar(10),>)
GO
```

At the moment i am looking at this tutorial: https://sqlchoice.azurewebsites.net/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/csharp/win/step/2.html

However i would really like to know what the best/most professional way in order to insert and update data against this? as it I will seed some columns but then update later on, to date i have not needed to use sql data as yet so would really like to start with a good footing from experienced programmers.

my connection method is this which works great:

```
    SqlConnection _sqlConnection;
    SqlDataReader _sqlData;
    SqlCommand _sqlCommand;

public bool ConnectToDB()
{
    try
    {
        string conString = $"Data Source={TEST_Config.Database_Host};Initial Catalog={TEST_Config.Database_Name};Integrated Security={TEST_Config.Integrated_Security}";
        _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        _sqlConnection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception CTDB_EX)
    {
        log.Info($"Issues Encountered Connecting to the Database: {CTDB_EX.Message}");
        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            log.Debug($"STACK_TRACE: {CTDB_EX.StackTrace}");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

After this i ran through a number of tutorials but struggled with larger column sets and handling them in the best way, I then decided to create a class for the columns with getters and setters ie

```
public string _Identifier {get;set;}
etc etc
```

but at this point i stalled and decided to look for advice.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear me.. Why are people still writing tutorials that promote stuffing business logic code full of strings containing SQL? If you applied for a job with me and sent that in as some example code you'd written, your resumé would go straight in the bin without even being viewed. Try https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=getting+started+with+entity+framework for pointers to learning a data access methodology that employers WANT to see on a resumé. Feel free to learn SQL independently to understand the data access back-story but don't assume your code has to be full of it

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at this, this is the reason behind the post as i was not happy with what i was reading and would like to gain the best possible way forward in handling data with code.

Comment: I would suggest looking at Dapper for what you are looking to do - https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: There's certainly a huge value in learning SQL at the same time as using EF to do your data access (EF uses SQL under the hood), but in the same sort of way that there's a huge value in learning about HTTP/SMTP protocol but using System.Net.Mail or WebClient to send mails/download files rather than doing your own socket programming and pushing `GET / HTTP1.1...` down the wire/reading the response back as bytes.. Use abstractions and libraries wherever possible, while maintinaing a healthy appreciation for what happens at the base level (just don't reinvent the wheel) :)

Comment: and in addition to @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat 's comment - it's a good call, and there are a great many libraries that map objects to databases and do data access (nHibernate's another popular one) - pick whatever skills you need to get your job/whichever one you feel will help you cross-skill most easily for your next job

Comment: I'll recommend using EF in all cases (Even if the application is just doing one insert in one table only), this will benefit you and your application as well. Easier to maintain, expand, and also fun to code ;) .

Comment: Thanks all so far for the comments its been a great eye opener so far and i think what i will do it create a couple of duplicate projects and learn both sets of libraries ie EF and Dapper as from what i have seen these look much cleaner than (imho) rather ridiculous stringbuilding operations which limit function, create bloat and potentially leave room for security issues

Comment: @CaiusJard Many thanks for this i have already managed to get this up and running with data being inserted and retrieved correctly.
Reading through the generated classes also makes complete sense on how this is functioning and genuinely stunned how effective this is.
I will also look at dapper as per Ctrl_Alt_Defeat mentioned to as its always good to widen a toolset/understanding
Thanks All once again

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `.dbml` file in your project, using this you could manage all the database related activities with drag and drop database objects. It uses `LINQ` for all database transaction `(select, insert, update, delete)`.

Comment: DBML as In Linq to SQL? That 10 year old defunct data access method that is deprecated in favor of Entity Framework? C'mon.. The guy's had the foresight to realize that the 20 year old tutorial he's following has surely been modernized - do him the favor of a more up to date suggestion :) https://entityframework.net/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql

Comment: I will look into your suggestion, I prefer him to learn the quickest learning content. I do work in both DBML and Entity framework. Simple drag and drop a database table object is more than enough. Will this is offered in entity framework...?

Comment: It's not about that so much, as learning a set of skills relevant to today's world. Linq to SQL's time has passed

Comment: I read the article about EF vs LINQ to SQL from your link. As you said EF is better to learn straight away. I supported your comments too.